# Is there any available method for me to call a dynamic library that requires root permission through JNA？

Tags: java, linux, jna

As described in the title, the functions in the dynamic library need root permission to perform some system calls. If I use JNA, I don't know how to achieve this requirement.
Or is it a bad requirement?
Maybe I didn't provide more detailed code, but I'm sure it's a valuable question for me...

Comment: Execute your java program with root permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any available method for me to call a dynamic library that requires root permission through JNA？

No there isn't.  In UNIX / Linux, the only point when application permissions can be elevated is when using `exec` to execute a new process AND the executable has the "set uid" bit set in its file permissions.

This presents particular problems for Java.  It is totally unsafe to make the `java` executable a "set uid root" program.  The standard `java` executable is designed run *any* Java class supplied via the command arguments.  You can't restrict it to only running certain classes that are known to be safe to run as root.

In short, if your Java application needs root access to do something (in Java code or in a native code library), then it needs to have been started by the `root` user.

> Or is it a bad requirement?

It is an unimplementable requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about JNA will give your Java applications permissions it doesn't already have. If you need elevated permissions to execute a library function, you'll need to give those permissions to your Java program, usually by running it as a privileged user.